# What amplification can I apply to $y=\sin x$ for it to be a perfect oscillating arc?

Tags: trigonometry, transformation

A perfect arc is $y=\sqrt{|1-(x-1)^2|}$.
A sin wave is $y=\sin({\pi x\over2})$

I am curious how I can amplify the sin wave so that it's a perfect alternating arc.

In the link below you can see graphed each of these two equations, as well as the delta between them.  So in the sage code there's function $i(x) = $SOMETHING $\times f(x)$, where $f(x) = \sin({\pi x\over 2})$, but I want to replace the 'SOMETHING' with an expression that transforms the wave to 
$$y=\sqrt{|1-(x-1)^2|}+\sqrt{|1-(x-3)^2|}+\sqrt{|1-(x-5)^2|}... + \sqrt{|1-(x-n)^2|}$$

> In other words, I want $g(x):g(x)\sin({\pi x\over 2}) = \sqrt{|(1-(x-1)^2|}$ where $0<x<2$

I have no particular goal, I am just curious how I would go about solving that as currently I'm a bit stumped...

[sage math link to the various graphs](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyljsFuAiEQhu8kvAM3B8ta2DQ9mHD1MTSouEuywhawRZ9epu6hyfa2HJjJzzffUPS3ibAqK07J2V7YBQrfUsLqiTbfomfJeYDRvbd8XSaom0NfMYM5JlANlEbxfcsntp-xON3gnhfgZoBcv14pSX34AUrGIWTATLAimBRMyXpF48_h6h5W78yQrGCIHcbgfE5aSVWJ7ngKQ4i6v1mQG4l_wj1vk7JbrGz_KLH8avvF2o__tG6x9hO1gt2vzutGbVpsTdG1w7hgLLHWDBOTRnvKh2iyC1pRUoefoZqd3g==&lang=sage)

thank you kind internet maths wizards!

Comment: is it $0$ or "o" ? I am confused

Comment: replaced the 0 with 'SOMETHING', does that help?

Comment: $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{|1-(x-1)^2}|}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}x}$. I don't know what other kind of answer you are expecting.

Comment: I essentially want a general expression coefficient, a,  to y=a * sin(x), so such that the resulting sine wave will be perfectly round

Comment: @Wojowu the answer I seek is the generalized form that doesn't have the domain restriction of 0<x<2

Comment: for example, the blue line here is wrong: [graphs](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyljsFuwyAMhu9IvINvNR1JIap6mMR1j7GKtiRFSiEDurE9_bCW03qsD7b16fMP1XzahJu6EZxd3AgjVvHKGbRKrtxTgOwD4uJ3g9jWVZoepY9U0J4y6g5rp8X7IFbXP7h0DVvQu_FvocEZZ_kav5CzZY4FiUmoEpQErVpLNlzizf8482bn7CSQdlyiDyUbrXQzptM5zjGZ692h6hV9gF59WSOnpyOH_5H-6cgDRUr4vvlgOt0PtNpqDv1AuBJWNBvbN2Lz4s7lmGzx0WjO2vEv7Fp_GA==&lang=sage) as from 2<x<4 I would want the blue line to be the round circle underneath the red line, not exploding upwards like it is...

Comment: to get a square wave [a recursive sine graph](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9j0FuwyAQRfeWfIeRughu3NheZBOJRQ_QE1RVhR2IR8IwgnHj3L4Q25ndY-D9zxuMzBQvTcN3ZNbhNPip-bS9DvylH_0cbmNZLPJPBXFYDlVZmNkNjN5FkGAxsshnkvB9KYurnxQ6KT4IayDMGx8AAR0E5W5adPW5rS5lAWmMjOiEqTbatSdFpN31uaAo9whMce3qM9n3ur_Z6PWQrGdhaljL1PCYUqUVvtufzGrZuUscbv3grQ9ynLXAxupUapdXaVZ_zkc4QlcWTPKZQTH5tj9S7kR7GSY4SqCyiKO_C6YaVCQ98G9QSSu7xIuO0igbdfUPtUt3Ig==&lang=sage) looks like it would converge to perfectly flat and perfectly square, maybe I could ... reverse recurse to converge to perfectly round?

Comment: @albert: Does the graph $y = \sqrt{\pi^{2} - (\arccos \sin x)^{2}}$ have the shape ("consecutive semicircles") you're seeking?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, pretty close!!  This looks like the abs(g(x)) of what I want :)  just need the alternating waves to go down now...

Comment: well... it looks like abs(g(x)) but also with the wrong period as I want the semi circle function roots to line up with the sine wave function roots :) but still heading in possibly the right direction

Comment: @albert I added another answer. Is that what you meant by "sign/modulo+shifting"? I'll edit your answer with mathjax, should your expressions look like this: $\sqrt{|1-(x-1)^2|}$?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife yes that seems correctly formed with mathjax.  as for my terminology, it was pretty poorly phrased, I should just stick to the wording that I'm looking for g(x) such that f(x) = g(x) * sin(x) where f(x) plots to an alternating perfect arc

Comment: @Wojowu, I believe we need the reciprocal of your fraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}$If $\sgn$ denotes the signum function
$$
\sgn(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{x}{|x|} & x \neq 0, \\
  0 & x = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
the graph
$$
y = \sgn(u)\sqrt{|u| \cdot \bigl(\pi - |u|\bigr)},\qquad u = \arcsin(\sin x)
$$
(blue; $y = \sin x$ is black) seems to be what you're seeking:

[image: The sine function scaled up to semicircles]

Comment: It is... though I can't help thinking there's another solution that's in the form y=unknownexpression(x) * sin(x)... instead of using a sign/modulo + shifting... I'll accept your answer as the best one though :)

Comment: There is, as wojowu noted: Multiply and divide by $\sin x$, and (if you like) define the quotient to be zero at integer multiples of $\pi$. :) (The quotient, i.e., your unknown expression, blows up in absolute value like $|x - k\pi|^{-1/2}$ at $k\pi$; there's no _continuous_ function with the property you seek.)

Comment: Ok, so, time for me to learn, how do you know that there's no continuous function with the property I seek?

Comment: Let $f$ denote an arbitrary function vanishing at the zeros of the sine function. The identity $f(x) = g(x) \sin x$ implies $g(x) = f(x)/\sin x$ (for $x$ not a root of sine). In the case at hand, $f$ has "a root of order $1/2$ at $k\pi$", while sine has simple roots; the quotient $g$ therefore blows up at $k\pi$. In more detail, $f(x) \sim c\sgn(x) \sqrt{|x|}$ near $0$, so $g(x) = f(x)/\sin x \sim c/\sqrt{|x|}$; the behavior at other roots is similar thanks to symmetry. So: $g$ is uniquely determined away from $k\pi$, but unbounded "near" $k\pi$. Consequently, no continuous $g$ exists.

Comment: I wonder if such a function could be written as a Fourier Series. This may be more in line with what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sqrt{\left({\pi\over a}\right)^2-\left({\pi\over a}-|x-{2\pi\over a}|\right)^2}$$ conincides with $\sin({ax\over 2})$ at its zeros and gives you recurring semi-circles for $0\le x\le{4\pi\over a}$. In case $a=\pi$ the graphs are

[image]